# How to do a vlookup for a few millions row, without running into memory problems?

Tags: r, out-of-memory

Looking to write a code that can perform a vlookup.

I have several excel files (each containing ~1m rows (excel file limit) that act as lookup tables.

I then have an excel sheet with two columns that I need to look up - these two columns can't be merged, as the results must be kept seperated.

First I load the files that contain the tables I want to lookup in:

```
All <- lapply(filenames_list,function(filename){
  print(paste("Merging",filename,sep = " "))
  read.xlsx(filename)
})
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, All)
```

Then I load the files I want to look up:

```
LookUpID1 <- read.xlsx(paste(current_working_dir,"/LookUpIDs.xlsx", sep=""), sheet = 1, startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE, cols = 1, skipEmptyRows = TRUE, skipEmptyCols = TRUE)
LookUpID2 <- read.xlsx(paste(current_working_dir,"/LookUpIDs.xlsx", sep=""), sheet = 1, startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE, cols = 2, skipEmptyRows = TRUE, skipEmptyCols = TRUE)
```

I need to load the file twice, as I need to perform a lookup on both column 1 and 2.

And then the actual vlookup:

```
# Matching ID
FoundIDs1 <- merge(df, LookUpID1)
FoundIDs2 <- merge(df, LookUpID2)
FoundIDs <- merge(FoundIDs1, FoundIDs2, by = NULL)
```

The issue is that my PC runs out of memory when running the last part of the code (the actual Vlookup);

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1715.0 Gb

Comment: what's the dimension of your data? do you need to keep all the variables every time you do a look-up/merge? Also, CRAN not the best database toolset around. If you're doing large data-set, you should look at dedicated solution like sql to help you with the queries.

Comment: So the lookuptables are currently containing ~ 10 excel files with a million row each. Each table only has 2 columns, which are the ID column and the outcome column (what I want to return)

The table that I want to append the outcome to, is only 1 column with IDs.

Comment: Also, the excel files are only ~ 18 mb each and since I have 8 GB of ram, I find it weird that it has become an issue